# Open an image in gallery using file path

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i have an image file path stored in my database. Now using it i want to open images from SD Card in my gallery. How can i do that. I have seen methods from Uri and using this method but i am getting error

```
File file = new File(filename);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivity(intent); /** replace with your own uri */
```

How to fix it,

```
04-20 08:42:23.516: E/AndroidRuntime(16815): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/My%20App/image_umxto_1.jpg }
```

best regards

Comment: what uri you are using must be lke "file://sdcard/...."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(filename)), "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
```

Use this code and tell me

Comment: I get thts error `android.os.FileUriExposedException:// filepath goes here//exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the below code:::

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + "/sdcard/test.jpg"), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: the same error as given in the question appears on using the code you have given

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below line to do your task:::

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/16"))); /** replace with your own uri */
```

Comment: i have file path not uristring

Comment: you can convert file path to uri...Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath))

Comment: uri.fromfile gives FileUriExposed exception in newer android versions

Answer (score 0):

I was getting FileUriExposedException and after some digging found solution. Convert file path to URI and pass it in intent.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getContext(),
                    new String[] { getImagePath() }, null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            Log.i("onScanCompleted", uri.getPath());
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
```

Hope it helps.